# Why does namedtuple in python need a name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, namedtuple

Why do we need to mention the name `Card` for `namedtuple` like below?

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])
```

I think a simple `Card = collections.namedtuple(['rank', 'suit'])` can actually give the same effect right?

For example I can have the same information in a dict like:

```
card = dict({'rank': 'A', 'suit': 'spade'})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that won't give the same effect.

> `collections.namedtuple`:
>   Returns a new tuple **subclass** named typename...

`namedtuple` returns a subclass of the tuple type, not a tuple  instance.

The `name` parameter specifies the class name of the new subclass, just as you would define a regular Python class and give it a name:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'], verbose=True)
class Card(tuple):
    'Card(rank, suit)'

    __slots__ = ()

    _fields = ('rank', 'suit')

    def __new__(_cls, rank, suit):
        'Create new instance of Card(rank, suit)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (rank, suit))
    ...
```

A quick type check clears every doubt:

```
>>> type(_), issubclass(_, tuple)
(<class 'type'>, True)
```

So there, you have `namedtuple`, a *factory function* that returns a subclass of a tuple.

Comment: It could be anonymous right? I mean you can capture the returned object and do whatever you want with it. For example `a = {}` is needed if you need to retain the `dict`. Otherwise it could be garbage collected immediately.

In other words that name is really not needed is what I thought. However it helps to have one.

Comment: How would you instantiate an anonymous class? Note that `a = {}` creates a dict **instance** via the literal, not a dict subclass

Comment: Do you mean `namedtuple` is actually a class internally?

Comment: Just to complement the very good answer: in practice the creation of the subclass allows things like `.__class__` and `.__class__.__name__` to work beautifully and as expected. Also a very good and free implementation of `__repr__`.

Comment: @Nishant `namedtuple` is a function, which returns a new subclass of tuple. `<function namedtuple at 0x7f3b4ae7c500>`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, see this example a = lambda x:x, I can create a function using an anonymous object. It is not the best way, but this is possible right? Likewise I thought that the name really exists for the purpose of `__repr__` like the answer from @AndrewGelnar and it is not something mandatory? `tuple` doesn't have a name. `namedtuple` need not have a name as long as it can be indexed with the field names.

Comment: @Nishant `lambda` functions are anonymous functions. `tuple`'s name is tuple (class name). A `namedtuple`'s name is the name of the new class returned. It's the design philosophy, else it won't be called **`named`** `tuple`

Comment: But why is there a need to assign to a variable? Why can’t Python expose the first argument to namedtuple in the current namespace? A flip of the OP.

Comment: @DonSlowik *Explicit is better than implicit*. Exposing the name implicitly in the current namespace **assumes** everyone who uses `namedtuple` understands the inner workings of the factory function. However, not everyone does and not everyone needs to. Better to be explicit.

Comment: A more practical question is: Is there any harm in using a "garbage" name? What about `'int'`? Or even the empty string `''`? For example,  `Card = namedtuple('int', ['rank', 'suit'], verbose=True)`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Using an empty string won't work as `''.isidentifier()` must be `True` for the passed name. Using a name such as `int` also has little or no effect as the new `int` class is usually namespaced under the current module, so the built-in `int` still works. But better to not use it ayway to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, maybe my real question is: could problems occur if I pass in the same fieldname twice, but with different fields? Will the second call interfere with the first type created. I would like some guarantee that `typename=''` will create a unique type each time

Comment: What is the consequences from doing `Card_X = namedtuple('Card_Y', ...`?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a named tuple like this

```
from collections import namedtuple
Card = namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])
```

You are creating a new class (which is a subclass of `tuple`)

```
>>> Card
<class '__main__.Card'>
```

So for clarity, it is nicer to specifically name the class, as it has it's own specific properties (`__init__` takes two arguments, the first becomes the instance's `rank` attribute, and the second becomes it's `suit` argument).

The `namedtuple` author could have used the same name for all of these classes, so it would have looked like `<class 'collections.NamedTuple'>`. But then how do you tell which one is your new `Card` class, and which one is your new `PokerHands` class?